# Python and Sikuli - Selecting from a list (multiple)

Tags: python, sikuli

Asking around a different way of doing this.

I am trying to look at the screen, decide if an image exists (from a list) and choose any that are there, then click "go". If none of the list items are there, it would execute `click("go.png")` and carry on.  If there are any list items there, it clicks it and then executes the `click("go.png")`

```
wait("start.png", 10)
click("start.png")

class gameOne():
    def pickone():
        imageFile = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png"]
        if exists(imageFile):
            click(imageFile)
click("go.png")
```

With this, the `click("start.png")` and `click("go.png")` work. It seems to just skips the class. No error is given.

Comment: I am not familiar with Sikli, but it seems like you aren't creating any instance of this class. Try `mygame=gameOne()`, and then `mygame.pickone()`.

Comment: @Bitwise Thanks, I am not sure how that would be structured. Could you show what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the class correctly, I'm not sure how you are expecting this to work, but you don't need that for what you're doing:

```
wait("start.png", 10)
click("start.png")    

imageFile = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png"]

if exists(imageFile):
    click(imageFile)

click("go.png")
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: I was using the class because with out that (using your example) I get the error: `[error] Region.exists: seems that imagefile could not be found on disk` And, the images are definitely there.

Comment: are you showing your entire code? perhaps update your question with this, i'm having trouble understanding the context